# Mysql multiple where with post data php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am working to filter data according to the provided posted fileds from php file. 
I have 10 input fields and user are supposed to fill any number of fields as they are not required fields.
So I may get 10 fields out of 10 or none too. How can I write where condition with mysql query to filter data from database only for posted data fields .

```
<?php

if (!empty($eventInfo))
    {
    $event = $eventInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $event = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($wildInfo))
    {
    $wild = $wildInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $wild = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($additionalInfo))
    {
    $additional = $additionalInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $additional = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($humanInfo))
    {
    $human = $humanInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $human = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($livestockInfo))
    {
    $livestock = $livestockInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $livestock = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($cropInfo))
    {
    $crop = $cropInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $crop = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($propertyInfo))
    {
    $property = $propertyInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $property = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($otherInfo))
    {
    $other = $otherInfo . ',';
    }
  else
    {
    $other = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($year))
    {
    $where = "(EXTRACT(year FROM `e`.event_date_time) = '$year')";
    }
  else
    {
    $where = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($month))
    {
    $where1 = "(EXTRACT(month FROM `e`.event_date_time) = '$month')";
    }
  else
    {
    $where1 = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($animal))
    {
    $where2 = "`e`.animal_type = '$animal'";
    }
  else
    {
    $where2 = NULL;
    }

if (!empty($conflictType))
    {
    $like = '`e`.event_types like %' . $conflictType . '%';
    }

$query = "SELECT $event" . "$wild" . "$additional" . "$human" . "$livestock" . "$crop" . "$property" . "$other" . "`d`.`value` as `event_district`, `vdc`.`value` as `event_vdc_munic`   FROM `event_info` as `e` LEFT JOIN `wild_animal_info` `wa` ON `e`.`event_id` = `wa`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `human_victim_info` `hv` ON `e`.`event_id` = `hv`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `livestock_destruction_info` `lv` ON `e`.`event_id` = `lv`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `crop_destruction_info` `c` ON `e`.`event_id` = `c`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `proprty_destruction_info` `p` ON `e`.`event_id` = `p`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `other_destruction_info` `o` ON `e`.`event_id` = `o`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `additional_info` `a` ON `e`.`event_id` = `a`.`event_id` LEFT JOIN `district_info` `d` ON `e`.`event_district` = `d`.`id` LEFT JOIN `vdc_munic_info` `vdc` ON `e`.`event_vdc_munic` = `vdc`.`id`";
$select_table = pdo_db()->query($query);
$rows = $select_table->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now How could I add where at the end of query if any of year, species, month and conflict type fileds are empty / not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following solution:

1. First we've to find out whether there is any condition or not in WHERE clause. The if condition is true as soon as any one of the first encountered condition is true.

   `if($where1 || $where2 || $where3 || ...){
            $query = ' ... WHERE dummy-condition';
     }`

Note: you can set condition as id(Primary Key) is not null inside the dummy condition, as this condition is always returns true.

2. Then you can individually check for the conditions.

   `if($where1)
            $query = $query + ' AND condition($where1)';
      if($where2)
            $query = $query + ' AND condition($where2)';`

The final query will have WHERE clause with at least one condition i.e. dummy-condition.

Comment: Grazie Signor !